# CURL response as Array

Tags: php, arrays, curl

When the CURL response is returned in format like below.

```
Array
(
    [timestamp] => 20150409065254
    [callback_status_code] => 200
    [fingerprint] => 252839e4790446a4bdd3a353aa232281a7a0b464
    [txnid] => 219773
    [merchant] => ABC0001
    [restext] => Approved
    [rescode] => 00
    [expirydate] => 052016
    [settdate] => 20150409
    [refid] => t1
    [pan] => 444433...111
    [summarycode] => 1
    )
```

is there any way to access its data as array. **Its just in array format not array**

I'm using following code.

```
$options = array(
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,   // return web page

    );

$param = http_build_query($data);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$param);
curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
$content  = curl_exec($ch);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
echo $content;
```

Any help guys ???

Comment: Get whoever is supplying the array to use `json_encode()`. Then, when you get the data, use `json_decode($response, true);`

Comment: No. That output looks like the result of `print_r()`. It's designed to be human-readable, but it's not possible to parse it reliably.

Comment: @hd its from third party I can't access to that.

Comment: @JobinJose then contact them as that seems more like a debug message  (human readable array `print_r`) than a usable response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try the print_r_reverse() function described here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php#93529

So then you would define this function somewhere, and change the last couple lines of your code as follows:

```
...
$content = curl_exec($ch);
$myArray = print_r_reverse($content);
$status = curl_getinfo($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// Do something with $myArray
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Did you follow the instructions in that link I sent you? Did you create that function? What exactly is happening when you try execute that code?

Comment: I copied that function then tried this `$ar = (print_r_reverse($content));
echo $ar['pan'];` but its empty

Comment: instead of runing `echo $ar['pan'];` Try running `var_dump($ar);` and take a look to see what is outputted. See if it is what you expect.

Comment: it work but that not necessary to use `print_r_reverse` even `print_r()` do the same it just out put the sting not in array format!!.

Comment: I've just tested, and it works perfectly. Look at the code here: http://pastebin.com/taeK8iT8

Comment: Yes its worked ! , when I check the CURL output it has a <pre/> tag too. thats why its not worked for me . thanks . Should I can trust this function ?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, it doesn't work: https://eval.in/310604 (copied and pasted from your pastebin link)